# How to enable code folding with conditional blocks in PhpStorm (JetBrains)?

Tags: php, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, code-folding

I was wondering if there is a way to enable PhpStorm (or any other JetBrains tool that deals with `.phtml` files) to recognize conditional blocks when collapsing units of code.

I have this example:

```
<div class="parent">
    <?php if (condition) : ?>
        <div class="div1">
    <?php elseif (conditionTwo) : ?>
        <div class="div2">
    <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- Conditional block ends here -->
    </div>

<!-- Parent container ends here -->
</div>
```

PhpStorm (by default) allows me to collapse `div2` (with the first `</div>`), therefore `div1` will need to collapse with the last `</div>`, which is meant to be collapse with `parent`.

I have attempted to adjust settings, but with no success.

Microsoft's Visual Studio Code has the correct behavior:
[image: VSCode correct collapse behavior]

As you can see, in VSCode you are not allowed to collapse on `<div>`'s that are inside the `php if` block.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be configured with given code sample. You can submit this to JetBrains tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue for developers to look into it & address in next IDE versions.

Comment: The issue has been forwarded to JetBrains

Answer (score 1):

Really, the issue here is how you're writing the code.  It would be cleaner (and remove the edge case of not having a final `else` if you did something like

```
<div class="<?= condition ? 'div1' : 'div2'; ?>">
```